# eps converted from PDF using ghostscript looks bitmapped

Tags: windows, ghostscript, eps

I am trying to convert pdf file to eps using ghostscript. EPS converted successfully with cropped white background. Also it is selectable. But converted eps looks bitmap when i zoom.

my syntax is as below:

`gswin64c -q -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile="D:/sample.eps" "D:/sample.pdf" -o -`

Input PDF is not scanned pdf or any rasterized image in that. only searchable text in that pdf.

Is there anything i missed, or is this the problem with ghostscript?

regards,
Srikrishnan

Comment: Most likely the PDF file uses some feature which is not compatible with PostScript level 2 (which is why eps2write has a 2 in it). That could be a myriad of thigs; transparency, unsupported font format.... When the ps2write device (or eps2write, which is merely a subset) encounters content which it cannot preserve it renders it to an image.